# Windows Phone Runtime Component xap file missing dlls

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8

The compiled xap file for my application do not contains all dlls.
The Windows 8 Phone Project references a Phone Runtime Component, which also references a Windows Phone Shared DLL. The Shared Dll are not copied to the xap container and not deployed to the phone and the application dies.

If i manually adds the missing dll and deploy the xap to the phone after it works. But whenever i deploy from VS12, the dll are missing.

How to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adding a reference to the "Windows Phone Shared DLL" directly for your top-level project? That would solve this problem.

Comment: That worked. So its not possible to link directly to the build files from another project?

Comment: try to "add as link" from build output